# code to open two links in same tab

Tags: vba, excel, google-chrome

I need to open two links in same tab in Google chrome browser. Below is the code I have tried, But I'm getting "File not found" error in line Browser = Shell(Chromepath & "-url URL1"). After opening the first URL(a login page) then it should navigates to second URL in same tab.

```
Sub Defects()
Dim ExtractliveApp As Variant
Dim Browser As Variant
Dim URL As Variant
URL1 = "go/ExtractliveApp"
URL2 = "https://Extract.live.com/SelfServiceExtracts"
Chromepath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
Browser = Shell(Chromepath & "-url URL1")
Browser = Shell(Chromepath & "-url URL2")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo in your code:

```
Browser = Shell(Chromepath & "-url URL1")
Browser = Shell(Chromepath & "-url URL2")
```

Should be

```
Browser = Shell(Chromepath & " -url " & URL1)
Browser = Shell(Chromepath & " -url " & URL2)
```

You need a space after the `Chromepath` as otherwise the Shell is looking for `chrome.exe-url` which it can't find (hence the error).  I also fixed the use of your URL variables as they will need to be outside the quotes so that they are referenced correctly.  Leaving them inside will cause them to be treated literally and Chrome will attempt to browse to URL1 rather than your link.

Comment: Thanks Dave. After applying your code, I'm getting error - "Invalid procedure call or argument" in line Browser = Shell(Chromepath & " -url " & URL1). Can you please tell me how to fix this error?

Comment: URL1 in your code doesn't really look like a proper web address, I'd say that's your issue.  Replace it with a Google URL and test again; if it works, then the issue is the URL you're supplying and you'll need to fix that...

Comment: I have given the correct URL , even though I'm getting the same error.