# Open URLs in 1 tab for Chrome using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, google-chrome

I'm trying to open various links one after the other with a delay of 2 minutes in the same tab of Chrome using the below code. But every time I execute, it opens in a new tab in Chrome.

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal Milliseconds As LongPtr)

Sub openGenericURL()

Dim genericURL As String
Dim shellURL As String
Dim browser As Variant
Dim sSleep As Variant


        sSleep = Sheet1.Range("G2")  'Set to 2 minutes

        For i = 2 To 5
            genericURL = Sheet1.Cells(i, 12)    'Reading From Excel Cells
            Debug.Print genericURL
            shellURL = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe -url " & genericURL
            browser = Shell(shellURL, vbMaximizedFocus)

            If i <> 5 Then
                Sleep (sSleep)
            End If
        Next i

End Sub
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/so0va.png)

Comment: You could try to terminate/kill `shellUrl` in the end and then open the new tab. Or refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37790864/7690982)

Comment: The first and every time through your loop will open a new tab.  You would have to capture that tab after your first loop and then reference the tab directly.

Comment: How do we capture the tab and reuse it. Any suggestions ??

Comment: @danieltakeshi gave you the link above `Or refer to this`   the `this` is a link

Comment: @jsotola the link provided by danieltakeshi does not work for my scenario. I did my due diligence before posting the question. :-)